# XCodegen is not detecting some downloaded Pods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, yaml, xcodegen

I converted my whole project to XCodegen.

My project has multiple modules and all the libraries are downloaded via Cocoapods.

[image]

But, I've got a problem on the SharedFrontend module.
In this module (Sharedfrontend) I import "Tracker" which from ATInternet-Apple-SDK, but XCode or project doesn't detect it, and give me a error saying: "No Such Module Tracker", BUT It has the Tracker on the pods, and it did download it...

That leads me think ( I can be wrong ) that the problem are the pods not being recognised on SharedFrontend, which is why I am here today.

My SharedFrontend .YML file:

```
        name: SharedFrontend
    options:
      minimumXcodeGenVersion: 2.25
      groupSortPosition: top
      generateEmptyDirectories: true
      deploymentTarget:
        iOS: "12.3"
    targets:
      SharedFrontend:
        type: framework
        platform: iOS
        settings:
          PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER: "pt.custojusto.SharedFrontend"
          GENERATE_INFOPLIST_FILE: YES
        scheme:
          gatherCoverageData: true
        sources:
          - path: SharedFrontend
            createIntermediateGroups: true
    
      SharedFrontendTests:
        type: bundle.unit-test
        platform: iOS
        sources:
          - path: SharedFrontendTests
            createIntermediateGroups: true
        dependencies:
          - target: SharedFrontendTests
```

Plus, above, a image of the Sharedfrontend module, which you can see the pods are there:

[image]

Plus, I've made a Script to run pod install every time xcodegen updates, which I think does not have anything to do with my problem itself, but can be helpful.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd cj-ios
xcodegen
cd ..
cd cj-pro/iosApp
xcodegen
cd ../..
cd cj-uicomponents/iOS/UIComponents
xcodegen
cd ../../../
cd cj-sharedfrontend/SharedFrontend
xcodegen
cd ../../
pod install
```

I hope you guys could help me, our give any hint. I am looking to this for a week now, and I didn't get any solution yet.

Really Thanks!